# Renaming a rails 4.1.0 app - Can't remove name from Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filenames, rubymine

I renamed my old `test` app to `demo`. I replaced `test` with `demo` everywhere that I needed to, and the app runs fine.

However, in Rubymine, my `demo` directory is labeled like this:

`demo [test] (~/demo)`

How can I get rid of `[test]` in that name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a `.idea/.name` file that has the project name. Source [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-10168) .